# BeautifulSoup extract data from certain columns from a table I am getting too much data out

Tags: python-2.7, beautifulsoup

I am trying to extract some data out of my Selenium Test Report html file.
I am getting too much data out of the table of rows and columns.
The data I would like to extract is all columns which have the class value "testcase" and there is a column below with a class value "popup_link" and the text value will say Pass or Fail.
E.g.

```
<td class='none'><div class='testcase'>test_000001_login_valid_user</div></td>
<a class="popup_link" onfocus='this.blur();' href="javascript:showTestDetail('div_pt1.1')" >
    pass</a>
```

I would like the text "test_000001_login_valid_user" and the text "pass"

There are lots of test cases in my report so I would like to iterate over the rows and get the test case name out and the pass or fail text.

My HTML snippet is:

```
    <table id='result_table'>
<colgroup>
<col align='left' />
<col align='right' />
<col align='right' />
<col align='right' />
<col align='right' />
<col align='right' />
</colgroup>
<tr id='header_row'>
    <td>Test Group/Test case</td>
    <td>Count</td>
    <td>Pass</td>
    <td>Fail</td>
    <td>Error</td>
    <td>View</td>
</tr>

<tr class='passClass'>
    <td>Regression_TestCase.RegressionProjectEdit_TestCase.RegressionProject_TestCase_Project_Edit</td>
    <td>75</td>
    <td>75</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td><a href="javascript:showClassDetail('c1',75)">Detail</a></td>
</tr>

<tr id='pt1.1' class='hiddenRow'>
    <td class='none'><div class='testcase'>test_000001_login_valid_user</div></td>
    <td colspan='5' align='center'>

    <!--css div popup start-->
    <a class="popup_link" onfocus='this.blur();' href="javascript:showTestDetail('div_pt1.1')" >
        pass</a>

    <div id='div_pt1.1' class="popup_window">
        <div style='text-align: right; color:red;cursor:pointer'>
        <a onfocus='this.blur();' onclick="document.getElementById('div_pt1.1').style.display = 'none' " >
           [x]</a>
        </div>
        <pre>

pt1.1: *** test_login_valid_user ***
test login with a valid user - Passed


        </pre>
    </div>
    <!--css div popup end-->

    </td>
</tr>

<tr id='pt1.2' class='hiddenRow'>
    <td class='none'><div class='testcase'>test_000002_select_a_project</div></td>
    <td colspan='5' align='center'>

    <!--css div popup start-->
    <a class="popup_link" onfocus='this.blur();' href="javascript:showTestDetail('div_pt1.2')" >
        pass</a>

    <div id='div_pt1.2' class="popup_window">
        <div style='text-align: right; color:red;cursor:pointer'>
        <a onfocus='this.blur();' onclick="document.getElementById('div_pt1.2').style.display = 'none' " >
           [x]</a>
        </div>
        <pre>

pt1.2: *** test_login_valid_user ***
test login with a valid user - Passed
*** test_select_a_project ***
08_12_1612_08_03
Selenium_Regression_Edit_Project_Test


        </pre>
    </div>
    <!--css div popup end-->

    </td>
</tr>

<tr id='pt1.3' class='hiddenRow'>
    <td class='none'><div class='testcase'>test_000003_verify_Lademo_CRM_DataPreview_is_present</div></td>
    <td colspan='5' align='center'>

    <!--css div popup start-->
    <a class="popup_link" onfocus='this.blur();' href="javascript:showTestDetail('div_pt1.3')" >
        pass</a>

    <div id='div_pt1.3' class="popup_window">
        <div style='text-align: right; color:red;cursor:pointer'>
        <a onfocus='this.blur();' onclick="document.getElementById('div_pt1.3').style.display = 'none' " >
           [x]</a>
        </div>
        <pre>

pt1.3: *** test_login_valid_user ***
test login with a valid user - Passed
*** test_select_a_project ***
08_12_1612_08_03
Selenium_Regression_Edit_Project_Test
*** Test verify_Lademo_CRM_DataPreview_is_present ***
aSelenium_LADEMO_CRM_DONOTCHANGE
File
498


        </pre>
    </div>
    <!--css div popup end-->

    </td>
</tr>
```

My code is:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

table = soup.select_one("#result_table")

for row in table.select("tr.hiddenRow"):
        print(" ".join([td.text for td in row.find_all("td")]))
```

How can i achieve this please?

Thanks, Riaz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check each row for both, if both exist then extract the text:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for row in soup.select("#result_table tr"):
    div, a = row.select_one("div.testcase"),  row.select_one("a.popup_link")
    if div and a:
        print(div.text.strip(), a.text.strip())
```

which gives you:

```
(u'test_000001_login_valid_user', u'pass')
(u'test_000002_select_a_project', u'pass')
(u'test_000003_verify_Lademo_CRM_DataPreview_is_present', u'pass')
```

Of course if they always go together we can simplify to:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

for div in soup.select("#result_table tr div.testcase"):
        print(div.text.strip(),  div.find_next("a", class_="popup_link").text.strip())
```

Comment: That is brilliant.  I just need to format it now, omit the u and put the pass aligned neatly like in a column so it appears in a nice line.  I will be sending this in an email to the dev and test team. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @RiazLadhani,no prob, the u means it is a unicode string, if you really wanted to remove it you would encode the unicode using `.encode("utf-8")`

Comment: Like this: print(div.text.strip().encode('utf-8'), div.find_next("a").text.strip().encode('utf-8'))

Comment: @RiazLadhani, exactly, presuming the data is utf-8 encoded which it often is.

Comment: That's great.  Thanks for your help.